# apple rejected phonegap ios app due to issue on ipv6 network

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-build, ipv4

Apple rejected my ios app build using phonegap due to failure on testing done using ipv6 network. All the APIs using in the app is on my domain (eg. mydomain.com) which is on ipv4 network. Is there any fix rather than changing serbver to ipv6 so that it can be deployed using ipv4 network settings

Comment: Try changing your network to ipv6 and upload application to store.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to say, but unfortunately you have to. support IPv6 if you want your app to be approved.

According to **Apple Documentation**:

> Compatibility with IPv6 DNS64/NAT64 networks will be an App Store
>   submission requirement, so it is essential that apps ensure
>   compatibility. The good news is that the majority of apps are already
>   IPv6-compatible. For these apps, it’s still important to regularly
>   test your app to watch for regressions. Apps that aren’t
>   IPv6-compatible may encounter problems when operating on DNS64/NAT64
>   networks. Fortunately, it’s usually fairly simple to resolve these
>   issues, as discussed throughout this chapter.

[Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010220-CH213-SW12)

> At WWDC 2015 we announced the transition to IPv6-only network services
>   in iOS 9. Starting June 1, 2016 all apps submitted to the App Store
>   must support IPv6-only networking. Most apps will not require any
>   changes because IPv6 is already supported by NSURLSession and
>   CFNetwork APIs.

Apple is not supporting IPv4 anymore but only IPv6.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way out other than supporting IPv6 networks. Check out this [official apple link](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=05042016a) for more info on the same.

However in your case, fixing this issue wont be tedious. Check out this [tutorial](http://www.brianjcoleman.com/tutorial-how-to-test-your-app-for-ipv6-compatibility/) that explains step by step procedure to test your app for IPv6 compatibility. Hope it helps. Cheers.